# During Outlook item registration Greeks and non Latin characters seems being recognized and replaced by ??? MailItem.SaveAs(path, [Object Type])

Tags: c#, outlook, character-encoding, vsto, outlook-addin

Dears,

By using * MailItem.SaveAs(sing path, [Object Type]) *

during Outlook item (.msg) registration on temporary folder (file system) to be processed after,

all Greek and non Latin characters seems being corrupted and replaced by ?????

even if I put  as object type

Does someone know how to fix this ?

It 's certainly related to Character Encoding (utf-8) but

I put olMSGUnicode or olMSG as [Object Type] in parameters without any success

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQVoh.png)

A solution to how to register an Outlook item containing Greek (other non Latin ) characters on a windows file system (temp folder or other folder) without being replaced by ?????
@Community here's is the complete class called

```
    public void Package(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
    {           
        string path = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\" + "mail.msg";            
        try
        {
            mailItem.SaveAs(path, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                this.Content = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(Content, 0, Content.Length);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Characters in the email itself? Subject? Body? Both? Or the characters in the filename?

Comment: The  subject of the email and the  name of the attached document in that mail. Wherever we have the non Latin characters τοῦἌρἌρεωςὁςἌρη

Answer (score 0):

> It 's certainly related to Character Encoding (utf-8)

Typically you can find the encoding page in the message body, see the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property.

To use a custom encoding you can use the following code instead:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
    {                                        
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            ProcessLine(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error happen just before. the error happened at                                                                  
    **mailItem.SaveAs(path, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);**

Comment: What is the actual file path string passed to the method?